# How to print an error message if two keys are the same in a HashMap? (JAVA)

Tags: java, oop, error-handling, hashmap, key

**How do you print an error message if two keys are the same in a HashMap? (JAVA)**

I want every key in a hashmap to be unique; how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. HashMap (key is always UNIQUE)

If you put the same key in HashMap it will overwrite the old key and value you have already inserted.

If you want to have error message to be printed the check for key must have done outside before the insertion.

Ex.

```
Iterator it = hashmap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry keys = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if(keys.getKey().equals(your_user_input)) {
             //throw exception, logs, or print your error msg.
     }
    it.remove(); //ConcurrentModificationException 
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of printing an error message to let the user know that they can't create another key?

Comment: You can extend HashMap with that capability

Answer (score -1):

Keys are always unique in a HashMap but when you are populating your HashMap you can do a check by using containsKey(Object key) method of HashMap, if it returns true then print your error. So it might look like this :

```
if(yourMap.containsKey(yourKey)){
   //print you error
}else{
   yourMap.put(yourKey,yourValue);
}
```